# React JS: Understanding State

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I'm a beginner with react JS and am trying to complete the tic tac toe tutorial they provided on their website, but I'm struggling to understand how the state is being changed through the code.

Heres a snippet of 2 components the game uses:

```
class Square extends React.Component {

   render() 
  {
    return (
      <button className="square"
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
        >
      {this.props.value} 
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {

    constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state =
     {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
    };
  }

    handleClick(i) 
  {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = 'X';
    this.setState({squares: squares});
  }

  renderSquare(i) 
  {
   return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
//this.renderSquare is called 7 more times to create the board 
- left out to make code here look slightly more concise

        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's what I don't understand: 
renderSquare is called first, passing in 0 as the argument for i. The square component is then called, passing in two properties - value and onClick. I just don't understand what's going on in the square component. onClick is assigned the anonymous function that was declared in the return statement of renderSquare, but how/when is onClick ever called? I'm not quite sure how onClick() works in this scenario.

I've read similar questions on here about state and I wasn't understanding the explanations given. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`<Square>` renders some HTML, as you can see in the `Square` class. That HTML includes a div element with the prop: `onClick={()=>this.props.onClick()}` React will translate this to a standard Javascript `onclick` event. The click handler that gets called when the user clicks on the div is whatever function has been passed to the `Square` component as its `onClick` prop: in this case `this.handleClick(i)` (where the value of `i` has been passed into the `renderSquare` function). With me so far?

When `this.handleClick(i)` is called, it uses `setState` to set the value of `this.state.squares[i]` to `'X'`. This value is picked up inside each Square (`value={this.state.squares[i]}`) and rendered inside the Square by `{this.props.value}`. Thus when the user clicks a square, an X is rendered inside the square.

I hope this clarifies things!

Answer (score 0):

> but how/when is onClick ever called?

`onClick` is called whenever the Square is clicked in the browser.

To be more specific, `onClick` is called when the `onClick` in the button in the Square component is called.

```
class Square extends React.Component {

   render() 
  {
    return (
      <button className="square"
        // here!
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
        >
      {this.props.value} 
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

This `button.onClick` is a React-provided function that hooks into the button's `onclick` method, just like regular javascript.

Answer (score 0):

So to fully explain what is happening here, the first thing is to understand why it's important to keep component logic in parent components where possible. It's so it keeps the square component more reusable for the future since the job of the square component is to just render simple html and not worry about anything else.

So when you go to render the square we are actually passing the parent components function as a prop:

```
renderSquare(i) 
{
   return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }
```

So now imagine if square was a function and the argument it takes is a function it basically would look like this

```
function Square(onClick) {
  //so now you have access to the parents "handleClick" method
}
```

That is a distilled example above but in react it would actually be in the props object so you would access it in your example with the `this.props.onClick`. So when the square gets clicked it will run the function like so `this.props.onClick()`. Remember this is calling the parent components `handleClick` method that was passed to the square. Also the i is cached in the function call so if you clicked on the 6th square its index would be 5. So when it goes to set the state it will set the state for the 6th square (5 index in array) to be an 'x' in the parent component.

Now since the state got set the component will re-render due to how lifecycle methods work in React. So it will loop through each state that is stored and pass that value to the square that it should display.

edit: Also if you want to know what events are given to you in react I would suggest reading these two:

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: im confused by this command right here:                                                             onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
(this is in the square component) How does this call the handle click button? nothing is being passed into that function so there's a bit of disconnect for me there.

Comment: React has default events on html elements. So that onClick is a react event that is executing an anonymous function which calls the onClick passed down by the parent  in the props. That props.onClick could be named anything but they chose to name it onClick which might be adding to the confusion. I would actually change the name of that props.onClick to onSquareClick.

Comment: That is starting to make sense. Why do you have to have "onClick={() =>" before you put this.props.onclick? Why can't you just put "this.props.onclick"?

Comment: The onClick is basically an event that fires when an action is met. So normal html entities can register a onClick even which will fire a callback function. So when you put that onClick function on the html item it has a callback which you can pass a function to. For components, setting that onClick is basically like passing a prop called "onClick" so it works differently in that case. But again for html elements you are accessing a native react event that takes a callback.